# What is this plant, growing in Utah, USA; called?

Tags: identification

This plant is growing in Utah, USA. Here are two pictures of it:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a young **weeping cherry tree**.

The main trunk is quite gnarled in this specimen (hence the supports, possibly from a cutting and not grafted?), but the hanging ("weeping") flowering braches are quite distinct.

Comment: Yep, it's a cherry.